# Включатель или выключатель?

Tags: этимология

Попалась такая картинка:

[image]

А действительно, почему он именно выключатель, а не включатель?)))))

Comment: Смешное воспоминание. Мой сын лет в 5-6 выражался так: "У подземного перехода выходов - которые одновременно и входы - два". Зануда был страшный!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще это особенность русского языка. Действительно, мы обычно щелкаем выключателем, а не включателем, при том, что в других языках речь идет именно о переключателе (*англ.* switch,  *венг.* kapcsoló, *нем.* Schalter, wechseln...). Сказать, что это имеет какое-то отношение к экономии электроэнергии сложно. То, что "выключатель" легче произносится.... Хм... "Переключатель" звучит ничуть сложнее. К тому же, есть и синомимы. Но, наверное, не 100%. Например, тумблер.

С другой стороны, здесь можно искать какие-то глубинные психологические мотивы. Язык - это до некоторой степени форма мышления. И, соответственно, получается он, в какой-то степени, определяет ментальность. Помнится даже роман был, "Вавилон-17", в котором люди, выучившие язык инопланетян, потихоньку переходили на их сторону, т.к. язык изменял образ их мыслей.

А переводчик гугля тот еще юморист на самом деле :-)

Answer (score 4):

По всей видимости дело в том, что при первичной электрофикации населения в 20-х годах ХХ века, проблема  была не включить лампочку, а выключить. Маломощные генераторы напряжение в сети давали лишь в определённое время и то на несколько часов, а затем электричество вырубали. Чтобы свет погасить раньше, лампу накаливания первое время приходилось выкручивать из плафона, что как вы сами понимаете, чревато ожогами. Выключатель же позволял свет именно **выключить** пораньше. Включить освещение до того как его подадут всем, всё равно возможности у людей не было, а следовательно и "включателю" взяться было неоткуда.

Слово выключатель на разных языках:

(Болгарский язык; Български) — изключвател; прекъсвач
(Чешский язык; Čeština) — spínač; vypínač
(Немецкий язык; Deutsch) — Schalter
(Венгерский язык; Magyar) — kapcsoló
(Монгольский язык) — унтраалга
(Польский язык; Polska) — wyłącznik
(Румынский язык; Român) — întrerupător
(Сербско-хорватский язык; Српски језик; Hrvatski jezik) — prekidač; sklopka
(Испанский язык; Español) — interruptor
(Английский язык; English) — circuit breaker; cutout; switch
(Французский язык; Français) — disjoncteur; interrupteur; déconnecteur; déclencheur

Comment: Все-таки электричество на Руси и до большевиков было известно!))) А уж выключателей хватало (Даль) :
> "**Выключатель** м. >выключательница
>ж. кто что-либо выключает."
"Царское Село (ныне г. Пушкин) - первый город в Европе, который сплошь был освещен электричеством. Протяженность электросети достигала 64 км."

Comment: @grumant, естественно выключать что-нибудь надо было и при Дале, правда сомнительно, что электричество, всё-таки даже к моменту смерти учёного, в 1872 году, электричество было большой редкостью. Да и заметьте, выключатель - это человек, **кто** что-либо выключает.

В словаре Брокгауза и Ефрона слова "выключатель" нет, а вот у Ушакова (1935 год) уже появляется, что косвенно мою версию подтверждает.

Comment: Я про то и говорю!))) Сначала человек (у Даля), потом и механизм появился...
> Ф. К. Сологуб. Путь в Дамаск (1910) Повернул выключатель, ― и вдруг неярким светом электрической лампочки в потолке озарился тесный альков, ― серый мрамор умывальника с медными, красивыми кранами, и громоздкая, нагло громадная кровать." 
(Нацкорпус)
> П. Н. Лебедев. Письма (1898) (50 периодов) тока, к нему трехполюсный выключатель и салазки с винтом для натягивания ремня с условием препроводить означенные приборы в Физический кабинет не позднее 15 января 1899 г.

Answer (score 1):

Завела слово "выключатель" в переводчик гугл, по-английски получилось"switch". "Включатель" перевелся также, но с вопросом: "Возможно, вы имели в виду выключатель".

Теперь ввожу оба слова: "выключатель включатель". Получаю: breaker switch

Самое смешное, что "выключатель выключатель" переводится точно также: breaker switch

Правда, с добавлением запятой между словами будет уже "switch, the switch"

По крайней мере в английском в слове "выключатель" нет "выключательного" смысла.

Comment: В английском выключатель - tumbler switch (тумблер переключения).

Comment: Молодцы, вышли из положения :-))  кстати, в русском тоже есть слово "переключатель", почему его не используют? Произносится оно не лучше и не хуже других.

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулась на еще одно слово, в названии которого отразилось только одно действие, из нескольких возможных:  ОТВЁРТКА - "отворачивать", "отвернуть", но ей можно и закручивать, заворачивать. В украинском языке название этого "орудия труда" - ВИКРУТКА (читается "выкрутка"). Тоже только один вариант

Answer (score 1):

Насчет отвертки пока не знаю. 
А с выключателем, полагаю, произошло некоторое переосмысление.
"Вы" ведь означает не только антоним "В", но и массу других интересных вещей:"Выварка" (полнота действия), "Вывеска" (нечто снаружи, при том, что внутри никакая не "ввеска"), "вырезка" (не антоним "врезке"), "вывод"(логический)... Значения самые разные. 
Думаю, что выключатель - из той же серии.

Да, насчет Даля. Не уверен в его трактовке значения (говорят, большой был фантазёр), но показательно, что само слово есть. Полагаю, что значит оно нечто иное. Выключить в те времена вроде бы использовалось там, где сейчас сказали бы "исключить". Каковое значение и посейчас используется в некоторых юридических бумагах. Т.е. если выключатель - человек, то это тот, кто что-то **исключает**, "выключает из рассмотрения", например.

Так может выключатель - это тот, кто **выключает темноту**? Шутка, конечно, но "в каждой шутке есть доля шутки".

Answer (score 1):

Выключатель, как собственно и переключатель и т.п. предметы это элементы из электротехники. И может быть будет правильнее рассматривать названия тех или иных приборов с точки зрения физических процессов. Когда то давно я задал вопрос о выключателе профессору электротехники, на что он ответил очень кратко и ёмко с точки зрения физических процессов. Включить это просто подать напряжение и замкнуть цепь - процесс очень прост. А вот выключить - это не только разомкнуть цепь и снять напряжение, а и прекратить электрический ток. Последнее действие очень сложный процесс, отсюда и важность процесса выключения, и название прибора.
[link text](http://elektrodok-nn.ru)